# If $p$ is a prime number, then $\Bbb Z_{pn} \cong \Bbb Z_{p} \times \Bbb Z_{n}$ for a random integer $n$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I don't think so, because $\gcd(p,n)$ is not $1$ for a random $n$, but I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: What do you mean with "a *random* integer $n$"? It is true that there are some counterexamples, but depending on how $n$ is chosen it may be that the result hold for *almost* every value of $n$...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\mathbb{Z_8}\ncong \mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_4}$ as $\mathbb{Z_8}$ has an element of order $8$ but $\mathbb{Z_2} \times \mathbb{Z_4}$ does not.

Comment: So it is true that if gcd(a,b) is not 1, then $\Bbb Z_{ab} \cong \Bbb Z_{a} \times \Bbb Z_{b}$ will never occur, or not?

Comment: Yes, you should see theorem 8.2 in Contemporary abstract algebra by J. Gallian

Comment: I don't have that book.

Comment: [here](http://math.boisestate.edu/~liljanab/MATH508/Contemporary_Abstract_Algebra.PDF)

Comment: Oke , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You're right.Take $n=p$. Then the group $\mathbf{Z}_{p^{2}}$ is cyclic,  $\mathbf{Z}_{p} \times \mathbf{Z}_{p}$ is not as every element vanishes when you add it to itself p times!

Comment: And it isn't possible that a cyclic group and a 'not cyclic' group are isomorphic? Can you explain why, please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: By thinking at it, i guess not. Because when you start (for example a=2 en b= 6:$ f([1]_{12})=([1]_{2},[1]_{6}) $ (neutral element must projected on the neutral element). Then  $f([2]_{12})$ must be $([0]_{2},[2]_{6})$  (f is an homomorphism) and so one. and at $f( [6]_{12})$ we are back at the beginning, so I guess the answer is no. Is this reasoning ok, or not? And if you work with other groups, the same results is also value, no?

Comment: Not quite... (those ones are not the only generators!). Let G be a cyclic group, and f an isomorphism from G to H. Let g be a generator of $G$, then $f(g)$ is a generator of $H$.

Answer (score 3):

You're correct. Take $n=p$. Then $\mathbb{Z}/{p^2}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p$ because the latter isn't even cyclic: Suppose $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_p=\langle (m,n) \rangle$. Then $(m,n)^p=(m^p,n^p)=(1,1)$, a contradiction since $(m,n)$ should have order $p^2$.

Answer (score 0):

If you have p=2, n=2. You will get a counterexample. And hence it can't hold for any n, but it could hold for some, like p=2, n=3.